# how to make image bootstrap responsive using div class

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design

need configure following div class to make My img tag responsive how can do this?

```
.center {// need responsive this div class
    position: relative;
    left: 510px;
    top: -20px;
}
```

this is the img tag

```
<img class="center" class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/img/technet-logo.png" width="100" alt="Technet Logo">
```

Comment: how to use img-responsive class inside this img tag?

Comment: see my answer below.

Answer (score 3):

You can't use two `class` properties within one element. So you need to merge it.

Instead of:

```
<img class="center" class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/img/technet-logo.png" width="100" alt="Technet Logo">
```

You need to do:

```
<img class="center img-responsive" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/img/technet-logo.png" width="100" alt="Technet Logo">
```